# Compile other languages on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I've a  Java Code that is evaluating programming-codes in C, C++, Java. Now, I want to compile those codes on AWS Lambda. Is there any way, we can compile C, C++ and java code there.

Answer (score 0):

Basic premise you have to satisfy is to have a single package that can be deployed to `Lambda`. This package should contain all required tools to be able to build your code.

You can try using `Amazon Linux EC2` instance to run your program and see what additional dependencies you need to include in your Lambda deployment package. Keep in mind the `Lambda` deployment is just a container and this container has system and package dependencies. If the system doesn't contain the tools you need, then you have to include these tools in your deployment package. `Lambda` containers run on `Amazon Linux` instances so you can evaluate your setup on one of those.

Comment: I can install packages through yum in amazon linux but I don't know how to bundle them up in the zip with java maven project. Do you have any idea about it or can you please provide a example for that?

Comment: You can't run yum in Lambda. You somehow need to evaluate what binaries, libraries etc you need and bundle them with your code. Complexity depends on the scope of your project.